# How to set flavor versionCode and versionName at once from string resource file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi i have currently 15+ flavors in my android project. I am changing the flavor's **versionName** and **versionCode** manually while making a release. How do i set the **versionCodes** and **versionNames** by a string value of all the flavors at once by declaring it in **String Resource File**.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/add-version-properties-file-to-your-android-project-8c7982552b1b have a look here.

Comment: thanks @deepakkumar that really saved my time !!